# How to make post request in Django TastyPie using ApiKeyAuthentication

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have resource like this:

```
class EntryResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Entry.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'entry'
        allowed_methods = ['post']
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
```

And try to make request to this resource according to [documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication.html#apikeyauthentication):

```
requests.post('http://localhost/api/entry/',
              json={"key1": "value1",
                    "key2": "value2"},
              headers={"content-type": "application/json",
                       "Authorization": "ApiKey",
                       "<username>": "<api_key>"})
```

But get 401.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from documentation:

> Authorization: ApiKey daniel:204db7bcfafb2deb7506b89eb3b9b715b09905c8

your request must be like this:

```
requests.post('http://localhost/api/entry/',
              json={"key1": "value1",
                    "key2": "value2"},
              headers={"content-type": "application/json",
                       "Authorization": "ApiKey <username>:<api_key>"})
```

Comment: Cool! it was so easy.